# jQuery to find the OK button

Tags: jquery

I have the following html generated as a result of using a jQuery plugin in my page.

**I want to find the Ok button using jQuery and then add some javascript to the click event of this button.**

**How would I do this?**

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
     <button class="dnnPrimaryAction" type="button">Ok</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:**

The complete html which is for a dnnAlert on my page is as below ( dnnAlert is a jQuery UI alert dialog implementation in DNN).

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front dnnFormPopup ui-draggable ui-dialog-buttons" role="dialog" aria-describedby="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" style="left: 810px; top: 816.39px; width: 300px; height: auto; display: block;">
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-id-4">Copy Successful</span><button class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close"></button></div>
<div class="dnnDialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-3" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block; min-height: 0px; max-height: none;">Copied code to clipboard</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button class="dnnPrimaryAction" type="button">Ok</button>  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the other HTML I'll make the selector as specific as possible:

```
$("button.dnnPrimaryAction:contains('Ok')").click(function(){
   //do something
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aVFV5/

Comment: I have added the detailed html under EDIT 1 on my post.

Answer (score 0):

**Using id.**

```
<button class="dnnPrimaryAction" type="button" id = "okButton">Ok</button>

$( ".ui-dialog-buttonset #okButton" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```